# Can an if and only if condition be stated alternatively?

Tags: logic

Can

$P \Leftrightarrow (\exists x: A)$ be stated alternatively as

$\overline{P} \Leftrightarrow \neg (\exists x: A)$

i.e.

$\overline{P} \Leftrightarrow (\forall x: \neg A)$ ?

Comment: What do you mean by $::$?  I haven't seen that notation before.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber: Removed it, it wasn't relevant to the question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$P \Leftrightarrow Q$ is the same as $P \Rightarrow Q$ and $Q \Rightarrow P$

Those may be converted as $\neg Q \Rightarrow \neg P$ and $ \neg P \Rightarrow \neg Q$

Which is then indeed what you are asking about: $\neg P \Leftrightarrow \neg Q$